# Web design Problems

Tags: php

Dear Friends I need you help.. First Little back ground..

I am creating a website in PHP using codeigniter.. the problem is the design of website has become so complex and perplexing that I can not wrap my head around it. Here is what I have done already and the problems...(please bear with me)

1. I am using MVC and the code is distributed in Views, models and controllers. However the code has become very long with hundreds of functions, each model is over 300 line.
2. AM using Classes (obviously) and common functions are bundled into libraries.Also I have created use cases of the basic functionality (using normal flow charts). However when I start programing (so many new things creep up) after a while there is no similarity left between the diagram and the program being written, it seems like an exercise in which I have to write first and draw later..
3. Every time some thing goes wrong and I have to fix a module I have to re learn HOW i did what i did since it is a inter mingling web of functions calling functions calling functions.
4. Am using Edraw mind map for basic diagrams but get hardly any help from diagrams since when ever i word on one (the diagram or the software) it takes a vary different shape from the other.

My questions are::

1:: Am I doing some thing wrong ? Is there more to organize the website code beyong using classes MVC and libraries.
2::How do other developers make diagrams and can I see some real life examples of their design.
3:: Any ideas on keeping the code organized any further

Any help form you will be highly appreciated..

Though Its a long shot but **is there a system in which one can add code to the diagram that he has developed rather than typing function after function in a long list of code.**eg when we design a module in a flow chart then instead of reverting to coding we can add code right there in the diagram????

Comment: the question is too broad and doesnt touch on web design but application design. try to break it up into smaller parts and include more detail. As for your questions: 1) likely, 2) UML 3) Architecture and Implementation Patterns

Comment: Y cant you try a framework like YII http://www.yiiframework.com having a large set of featuers http://www.yiiframework.com/features

Comment: @AkhilThayyil and what is that going to help? The question is not about features of a framework.

Comment: Sadly your question is too broad. However, you should investigate SOLID principles and start trying to apply them to your code. The pain your are experiencing directly relates to poor design choices that can be refactored. Come back and ask more specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: @Gordon Refer the features provided by Yii , if he use a good framewok , he can easily reduce the no of line of code as code is reused mostly in that case , also for creating views and all the f/w itself provide tools

Comment: I think this is the same mistake that I am making in designing